# Deploying RAM intensive application on Google Cloud App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, spacy

I'm trying to deploy a python API on Google App Engine.

My API uses Spacy NLP model to recognize text passed in parameter, and search for a result in a database.

The problem here is the size of the Spacy model. Itself it's little more than 500MB. When tested locally on my computer, each workers was a little more than 1GB. Knowing that I need to cacth potentials concurrent requests, I need at least 2 workers, in term of RAM it's around 2GB. GAE instances max ram are 2GB and each time I send 2 requests in the same time, my workers get killed because of a lacking or RAM.

I tested both uWSGI and gunicorn servers with the following parameters but nothing seems to work.

uWSGI :
`uwsgi --http-socket :$PORT --wsgi-file main.py --callable app --processes 2 --master`

gunicorn : `gunicorn --bind=:$PORT --timeout 90 --workers 2 main:app`

My questions are : Is it possible to catch concurrent requests with only 1 worker ? Is there any way to reduce the size of the NLP model ? What could be an other solution on GCP (not too pricey) to host my API if it's not feasible on GAE ?

Comment: This is perhaps a silly question, but do you need all the components in the pretrained spaCy model? They typically include an NER, a tagger and a parser. But let's say you don't need the parser, then you could load it without, save to file without the parser, and it'll take less space.

Comment: If i may ask, why GCP? There are a lot of other cloud services available some of which are more ram-optimized.

Answer (score 1):

If you serve HTTP traffic on App Engine you can use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs).

- Create a container, you [have example in python here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#containerizing)
- Deploy it on Cloud Run
- Customize your Cloud Run service

  - [Up to 4Gb of memory](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits) (maybe more soon!)
  - [Up to 4 CPUs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu)
  - [Pay as you use (round to the upper 100ms)](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing#cloudrun-pricing)
  - Customize the number of possible concurrent request with the [concurrency parameter](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency)

If the cold start is an issue, I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-solutions-to-mitigate-the-cold-starts-on-cloud-run-8c60f0ae7894)